# Не работает делегирование для <select>

Tags: javascript

Не работает делегирование, когда я хочу чтобы обработчик обрабатывал все события внутри `<select>`. Вроде всё делал по учебнику и пробовал разные типы событий, но всё равно, всплывает только элемент `<select>`:

[image: Логи браузера во вложении]

```js
const selects = document.getElementById('select_nav_option')
selects.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
})
```

```html
<select id="select_nav_option" class="dark_theme">
  <option class="option_config">Генератор конфига</option>
  <optgroup label="Генератор ACL">
    <option class="option_acl">CSC</option>
    <option class="disableContent option_acl">ZBUT</option>
    <option class="disableContent option_acl">BO</option>
    <option class="disableContent option_acl">Mini-CSC</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option class="disableContent option_vpn">Генератор VPN</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так и должно быть. `change` - это событие элемента `select`.

```js
const selects = document.getElementById('select_nav_option')
selects.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value, e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex])
})
```

```html
<select id="select_nav_option" class="dark_theme">
  <option class="option_config">Генератор конфига</option>
  <optgroup label="Генератор ACL">
    <option class="option_acl">CSC</option>
    <option class="disableContent option_acl">ZBUT</option>
    <option class="disableContent option_acl">BO</option>
    <option class="disableContent option_acl">Mini-CSC</option>
  </optgroup>
  <option class="disableContent option_vpn">Генератор VPN</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Как тогда сделать делегирование для "select" ?

Comment: @KirillInkin Что такое "делегирование для `select`"?

Comment: Когда обработчик "повешан" на "select" а event.target будет указывать мне на option который я выбрал в этом select при нажатии

Comment: @KirillInkin change - это событие элемента select

Comment: когда ставлю событие "input" происходит тоже самое. Точно должен быть способ. Я отказываюсь верить что у людей могут быть в приложении select с сотнями option, и они не могут повесить обработчик событий чтоб можно было понять на какой из option кликнул пользователь )

Comment: @KirillInkin Не хотите - не верьте. Я уже показал Вам, как получить выбраный `option` элемент. Если Вам нужно только значение, то еще проще - `e.target.value`.

Comment: Мои извинения. Я не увидел сразу что вы сделали правку в коде. Сейчас проверю )

Comment: Спасибо всё работает )

Comment: @KirillInkin Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.